# How to initialise nested structure variable?

Tags: c

```
struct date{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};
struct employee{
    struct nmadtype nameaddr;
    int salary;
    struct date datehired;
};
struct employee e[3];
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
struct employee e[i].datehired={2,2,16};
```

i want to initialise employees date on which they hired through datehired variable but i dont want to initialise each member of struct date individually (like e[i].datehired.month=2)so i tried the last step but it is giving compilation error so plz suggest a method that will even work if my 3 employees have different hired date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're attempting to do is an *assignment*, not an *initialization*, which is why it's failing.  An initialization is done at the time a variable is defined.

What you can do is use a compound literal:

```
e[i].datehired = (struct date){2, 2, 16};
```

This creates a temporary variable of type `struct date` and assigns its values member-wise to the left side of the assignment.

Comment: thanks for solving my problem its a great and short solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `struct date` variable with init values to do so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date{
     int month;
     int day;
     int year;
 };

 struct employee{
     struct date datehired;
 };

int main(void)
{
    struct employee e[3];
    struct date initVal= {2,2,16};

     for(size_t i=0;i<sizeof(e)/sizeof(e[0]);i++){
         e[i].datehired=initVal;
     }
}
```

Or using [Compound Literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date{
     int month;
     int day;
     int year;
 };

 struct employee{
     struct date datehired;
 };

int main(void)
{
    struct employee e[3];

     for(size_t i=0;i<sizeof(e)/sizeof(e[0]);i++){
         e[i].datehired=(struct date){2,2,16};;
     }
}
```

And the easiest and basic code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date{
     int month;
     int day;
     int year;
 };

struct employee{
    struct date datehired;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct employee e[3];

     for(size_t i=0;i<sizeof(e)/sizeof(e[0]);i++)
     {
         e[i].datehired.month = 2;
         e[i].datehired.day   = 2;
         e[i].datehired.year  = 16;
     }
}
```